# Kubuntu 12.04 loging failure

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, login, troubleshooting

When I load up Kubuntu 12.04 and I type in my password the loading screen only gives me one icon. After a minute it goes back to the login screen.

Can anyone please help me and tell what to do so I can log back into Kubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with starting up KDE - and not the lower level UNIX login.

Try logging in as a different user to figure out if this is an issue with just your account or with KDE.

Was this an upgraded system?

Try renaming .kde (or .kde4) and then login again. NOTE: this will lose all your KDE account configuration (and data).